# Difficulty returning some values in C#

Tags: c#, methods, int, return

So I'm going to simplify an assignment I'm working on. I'm sorry if it's crazy bad I'm very new to C#. I should add that the finalMethod call is within Main() and is the only thing in Main().

```
finalMethod(ifPossible(functionOne()), functionTwo()))

static int functionOne()
    {
        int number;
        Console.WriteLine("Enter a number: ");
        number = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        return number;
    }

static int functionTwo()
    {
        int number;
        Console.WriteLine("Enter a number: ");
        number = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        return number;
    }

static bool ifPossible(int x, int y)
    {
        if (x < y)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

static int finalMethod(bool x)
    {
        if (x == true)
        {
            Console.Write("Success");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.Write("Fail");
        }
    }
```

My problem is that I need to return the int values from the first two functions into the finalMethod function. This is probably going to require a lot of restructuring but any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: It's not clear what you're asking. Why not call `ifPossible()` from `finalMethod()` and just pass both `x` and `y` to `finalMethod()`? There are numerous answers on Stack Overflow already discussing how to return multiple values from a single method, but it doesn't really seem like that's even needed here. What have you tried? What _specifically_ did you have trouble with?

Answer (score 1):

You have a close `)` on a wrong place. Try this:

```
finalMethod(ifPossible(functionOne(), functionTwo()));
```

Try to do some refactoring like this:

```
static int getInputValue()
{
    Console.WriteLine("Enter a number: ");
    var input = Console.ReadLine();
    return int.Parse(input);
}

static bool ifPossible(int x, int y)
{
    return x < y;
}

static void finalMethod(bool x)
{
    if (x)
    {
        Console.Write("Success");
    }
    else
    {
        Console.Write("Fail");
    }
}

var number1 = getInputValue();
var number2 = getInputValue();

finalMethod(ifPossible(number1, number2))
```

Answer (score 0):

Couple of things in above code:
1.remove int return  value from finalmethod
2. ifpossible is taking 1 argument it should take two.

```
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            SomeClass.finalMethod(SomeClass.ifPossible(SomeClass.functionOne(), SomeClass.functionTwo()));
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
}
    class SomeClass
{
    internal static int functionOne()
    {
        int number;
        Console.WriteLine("Enter a number: ");
        number = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        return number;
    }

    internal static int functionTwo()
    {
        int number;
        Console.WriteLine("Enter a number: ");
        number = int.Parse(Console.ReadLine());
        return number;
    }

    internal static bool ifPossible(int x, int y)
    {
        if (x < y)
        {
            return true;
        }
        else
        {
            return false;
        }
    }

    internal static void finalMethod(bool x)
    {
        if (x)
        {
            Console.Write("Success");
        }
        else
        {
            Console.Write("Fail");
        }
    }
}
```